# How to parse username, ID or whole part using Ruby Regex in this sentence?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a sentences like this:

`Hello @[Pratha](user:1), did you see @[John](user:3)'s answer?`

And what I want to is get `@[Pratha](user:1)` and `@[John](user:3)`. Either their names and ids or just as texts as I quoted so that i can explode and parse name and id myself.

But there is an issue here. Names `Pratha` and `John` may include non-abc characters like `'`, `,`, `-`, `+` , etc... But not `[]` and `()`

What I tried so far:

```
c = ''
f = c.match(/(?:\s|^)(?:@(?!(?:\d+|\w+?_|_\w+?)(?:\s(\[)|$)))(\w+)(?=\s|$)/i)
```

But no success.

Comment: FWIW, that's an example of a library for your latest question, https://github.com/avivr/search-parser .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
/@\[([^\]\[]*)\]\([^()]*:(\d+)\)/
```

See [the regex demo](http://rubular.com/r/ErRMetYTNA)

**Details**

- `@` - a `@` char
- `\[` - a `[`
- `([^\]\[]*)` - Group 1: 0+ chars other than `[` and `]`
- `\]` - a `]` char
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `[^()]*`- 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
- `:` - a colon
- `(\d+)` - Group 2: 1 or more digits
- `\)` - a `)` char.

Sample [Ruby code](https://ideone.com/CvODHI):

```
s = "Hello @[Pratha](user:1), did you see @[John](user:3)'s answer?"
rx = /@\[([^\]\[]*)\]\([^()]*:(\d+)\)/
res = s.scan(rx)
puts res
# = > [["Pratha", "1"], ["John", "3"]]
```

Comment: I do not need `user:`. Just ID. Can we grab that only? And is there a specific difference between yours and @The fourth bird?

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. I just need name and ID. Like below. So output should be Pratha => 1, John => 3

Comment: BTW, I will probably drop `\B` because message (which user writes)  maybe doesn't have a space before `@` For example: `Hello@[Pratha](user:1)` As you can see there is no space after `Hello`.

Comment: @Pratha Ok, then `(?:^|\s)` was a mistake in your pattern. I updated the code, regex and demos.

Comment: @CarySwoveland True, I updated the answer. I was playing with some Ruby code from another SO answer trying out various approaches and this block remained.

Answer (score 1):

```
"Hello @[Pratha](user:1), did you see @[John](user:3)'s answer?".scan(/@.*?\)/)
#⇒ ["@[Pratha](user:1)", "@[John](user:3)"]
```

Since the line is not coming from the user input, you might rely on that the part you are interested in starts with `@` and ends with `)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use 2 capturing groups to get the names and the id's:

`@\[([^]]+)]\([^:]+:([^)]+)\)`

That will match

- `@` Match literally
- `\[` Match [
- `([^]]+)` 1st capturing group which matches not ] 1+ times using a negated character class.
- `\(` Match literally
- `[^:]+:` Match not :, then match :
- `([^)]+)` 2nd capturing group which matches not `)` 1+ times
- `\)` Match `)`

[Regex demo](http://rubular.com/r/QUt6mmmehM) | [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/SChkTN)

Comment: All answers are giving correct output, however, Wiktor's and yours parse user's separately. And your solution just parses ID which is perfect.

Comment: Just a question, do we need `\B` at start like Wiktor did? (to prevent start with a word)

Comment: @Pratha I have explained what `\B` does - it won't match `@` if it is inside of a word. Also, see my code snippet.

Comment: It depends on what you would allow to match, `\B` asserts the position where `\b` does not match.

Comment: @Pratha You could also use `(?<!\S)@\[([^\]\[]*)\]\(([^()]*)\)` [Demo](http://rubular.com/r/9jFB2o0jij) to make sure what is on the left if not a non whitespace character.